# get post base on latest date without comparision

Tags: wordpress

I have custom post type having meta value include last update date.
I have to get post id in which meta value having latest date without compare other date.
below is my wp query to get post id but it is not working.

```
    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'post_status',
            'compare' => '=',
            'value' => 'active'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'other_cpt_id',
            'compare' => '=',
            'value' => $cptID
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'post_last_update_date', 
            'value' => '', 
            'compare' => '>',
            'type' => 'DATE'
            )            
    ),
    'orderby' => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'ASC','ID' => 'ASC' ),
    'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using WP 4.2+**, you may try the following:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'post_status',
            'compare' => '=',
            'value' => 'active'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'other_cpt_id',
            'compare' => '=',
            'value' => $cptID
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'post_last_update_date', 
            'value' => '', 
            'compare' => '>',
            'type' => 'DATE'
            )            
    ),
    'orderby' => array( 'post_last_update_date' => 'ASC', 'ID' => 'ASC' ),
    'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);
```

**Some sources:**

General WP_Query: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

4.0+ orderby array: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/08/29/a-more-powerful-order-by-in-wordpress-4-0/

4.2+ orderby meta data: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/

Comment: it is not working...i need post id base on meta query in which last update date from meta value, no need of order by of post id.